# One view using two tables with data that might not be in both tables, Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a view that uses two tables. I have seen some examples shown here, but the only problematic part is that my tables can be of different size:

example:

Table A

```
    ID   COMPANY_ID FORM_JOURNAL_ID LIQ_GAS_BRAND RETAIL_PRICE WHOLE_SALE_PRICE
-------- ---------- --------------- ------------- ------------ ----------------
 11532        733             412           120        15601                0 
 11445        732             434           120           70                0  
 11440        730             412           120           10               15
```

Table B

```
    ID COMPANY_ID FORM_JOURNAL_ID INDIVIDUALS   ENTITIES   COMPLEX
------ ---------- --------------- ----------- ---------- ------------------
 11911        730             412         555          0                777 
 11913        733             412           0        785                  0 
 11444        733             434          55          0                  0
```

as you can see, tables are bound by COMPANY_ID and FORM_JOURNAL_ID and Table B has COMPANY_ID 733 with FORM_JOURNAL_ID 434 but Table A doesn't have those attributes.

What approach should be used in order to show all of the information, that is, if Table A doesn't have COMPANY_ID that is in Table B, then just show '0' in places of retail_price and whole_sale_price.

So far, I managed to create a query that can show data from both tables but only when each table contains data on specific COMPANY_ID and FORM_JOURNAL_ID:

Full query

```
FORM_JOURNAL_ID COMPANY_ID      RETAIL  WHOLESALE INDIVIDUALS   ENTITIES  COMPLEX
--------------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------- ---------- --------
        412        730          10         15         555          0        777 
        412        731          20          0          99          0      10001 
        412        733       15601          0           0        785          0 
        434        730          10          0           0          0          0 
        434        732          70          0           0          0          0 

        434        733           0          0          55          0          0
```

Last line should be there but it's not.

Thank you!

p/s the query:

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
select
t1.form_journal_id,
t1.company_id,
max(nvl((decode(t1.liq_gas_brand, 120, t1.retail_price)),0)) as retail,
max(nvl((decode(t1.liq_gas_brand, 120, t1.whole_sale_price)),0)) as wholesale,
max(case when t2.form_journal_id = t1.form_journal_id and t2.company_id = t1.company_id then     nvl(t2.individuals, 0) else 0 end) as individuals,
max(case when t2.form_journal_id = t1.form_journal_id and t2.company_id = t1.company_id then nvl(t2.entities, 0) else 0 end) as entities,
max(case when t2.form_journal_id = t1.form_journal_id and t2.company_id = t1.company_id then nvl(t2.ind_energy_complex, 0) else 0 end) as complex
from cs_fact_f43_liq_gas t1, cs_form_journal j, cs_fact_f43_trade_gas t2
group by t1.form_journal_id, t1.company_id
order by t1.form_journal_id
```

Comment: post the query you use to get this output

Comment: why are you using form_journal_id and company_id in both tables? which is your primary key?

Comment: @ajmalmhd04 primary key in both tables are their ids, if i get you right. i am using form_journal_id and company_id to link the values in both tables, form_journal_id contains info about report date and web-form can have several companies that can be distinguished by company_id

Comment: @user1150569 I was just starting to adjust my answer below to the specific query which you have since provided. I am a little confused by the max / decode lines. The decode part seems to be saying if liq_gas_brand is 120 return retail_price, is this what you intended?

Comment: @user1150569 Also, you seem to be referring to a third table (cs_form_journal) in the from clause, but not referencing it anywhere else. Is this table needed / relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all records from one table regardless of whether they are in the table you are joining to you need an outer join. To do this you just add (+) to the side of the join that may have records missing. However, looking at the example above you have records in Table A that are not in B and vice versa. For this you will need a full outer join. I don't know of a concise way to express this in oracle, but one way that should work is to use a union with an outer join both ways on each side e.g. try this:

```
select a.FORM_JOURNAL_ID, 
       a.COMPANY_ID, 
       a.RETAIL_PRICE as RETAIL, 
       a.WHOLE_SALE_PRICE as WHOLESALE, 
       nvl(b.INDIVIDUALS,0) as INDIVIDUALS, 
       nvl(b.ENTITIES,0) as ENTITIES, 
       nvl(b.COMPLEX,0) as COMPLEX
  from TableA a, TableB b
 where a.FORM_JOURNAL_ID = b.FORM_JOURNAL_ID (+)
   and a.COMPANY_ID = b.COMPANY_ID (+)
union
select b.FORM_JOURNAL_ID, 
       b.COMPANY_ID, 
       nvl(a.RETAIL_PRICE,0) as RETAIL, 
       nvl(a.WHOLE_SALE_PRICE,0) as WHOLESALE, 
       b.INDIVIDUALS, 
       b.ENTITIES, 
       b.COMPLEX
  from TableA a, TableB b
 where b.FORM_JOURNAL_ID = a.FORM_JOURNAL_ID (+)
   and b.COMPANY_ID = a.COMPANY_ID (+);
```

The nvl() functions are not needed normally as any missing data would just be null, but I have included these as you mentioned that you wanted to show zeros.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested and it works fine, now based on your answer i need to further develop the query. Thanks a lot Chris, I would upvote your answer, but don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: Okay, thanks for update. I don't think you need any reputation points to select the check (marking this as the accepted answer) if it has resolved your issue.